# Out-File ".\demo.json" Command is not working - No file getting written, hard-coded path seems to work

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a JSON using PowerShell command but when I am trying output the file, the code doesn't seem to work....

```
$stepBase | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File ".\demo.json"
```

However when I am hard-coding the path like this...

```
$stepBase | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File "C:\User\Desktop\JsonResult\demo.json"
```

This command seems to work and for readers information, I am using Powershell ISE in admin mode for writing the script.

Any suggestions why hard-coded path seems to work but I am not able to use ".\" - root as path for output.

Comment: "the code doesn't seem to work" - how are your asserting that? Does a subsequent call to `Get-Content .\demo.json` not work, or do you receive an error? What happens exactly? Please be mindful that only you can see your screen :) "I am using Powershell ISE in admin mode for writing the script." - then your default location is probably `C:\Windows\System32` - did you check for a file at `C:\Windows\System32\demo.json`?

Comment: I just check the directory you mentioned, yes the file is getting generated in C:\Windows\System32\ - Thank you for pointing out, i will try and point the directory from where the tool is being run...

Comment: In addition to Mathias's comment, if you're looking to use a relative path you can use automatic variables such as `$PSScriptRoot`. More info on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1